# undefined reference to myfunction

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

My develop environment is :
Windows7 + eclsipse + ADT + CDT + NDK (latest version)

The head file code:

```
#ifndef HEAD_H_
#define HEAD_H_

#ifdef HAVE_INLINE
#  if defined(__GNUC_STDC_INLINE__) || defined(GSL_C99_INLINE) ||       defined(HAVE_C99_INLINE)
#    define INLINE_DECL inline  /* use C99 inline */
#    define INLINE_FUN inline
#  else  /*the part real work, since I have define HAVE_INLINE */
#    define INLINE_DECL         /* use GNU extern inline */
#    define INLINE_FUN extern inline 
#  endif
#else
#  define INLINE_DECL /* */
#endif
extern "C" {
INLINE_DECL double add(int x, int y);

#ifdef HAVE_INLINE
INLINE_FUN double add(int x, int y) {
return x+y;
}
#endif

extern inline double ad(int x, int y) {
return x-y;
 }
}
#endif /* HEAD_H_ */
```

The cpp file is :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <head.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> 
#define  LOG_TAG    "OCV:libnative_activity"

#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGW(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
#endif

jstring
Java_com_igit_testcinline_MainActivity_main(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz){
    double c = add(1,2);  /*Error, undefined reference to 'add'*/
    double d = ad(2,1);
        .....
```

When I use NDK make, the error "undefined reference to 'add' " will occur in cpp file.
I don't know why the error occur, but the function ad() work well.

Comment: Have you tried removing all the complex inline macro hackery and then putting it back one bit at a time to see when the problem occurs? Assuming there's some good reason for having it at all.